# Load data dynamically in server-side

Tags: next.js

I want to load data dynamically in server-side due to security reason and want to know is it right approach.

I've read document while and found out preview mode seems fit for my issue, but seems redirect is required so I'm trying to do:

1. Imagine you're in `test/`
2. Button clicked by user and add data which has id of 123
3. Redirect to `test/123` and get data which has id of 123 on `getStaticProps`
   Is it right approach to load data dynamically in server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done implementing an example for this see: https://github.com/qkreltms/nextjs-tutorial02